# Move HDD dd image to Raid-0 Fake Raid array

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, dd

I recently robbed a spare 120Gb SSD from an old laptop with the intention to throw it in my desktop machine that had an existing SSD hdd of the same size.  My goal was to make a dd copy of my existing HDD that is currently setup to dual boot Windows 10 and linux mint 17.3, made a RAID-0 array using my Mobo's "raid" software with the 2 SSD drives, then dd the image back onto the one logical volume at double the size and a bonus speed improvement. At least, that was my plan...

Google searching has turned up limited information since everything seems to deal with dd'ing Raid-0 images to single drives. I want to go the other direction.

When running a *sudo fdisk -l* in a live Ubuntu instance after the drive installation, I see a "disk" labeled "/dev/mapper/isw_gchhbgcb_ssdRaid". My assumption was I could just dd the image back onto this volume and set this to boot in my UEFI settings. As you can see, I am now here asking for help to the SU community since this assumption doesn't seem to have worked like I expected.

The data is not critical, and I can just dd the data back to my original HDD to restore my original setup, but in the interest of education (and stubbornness), I would like to see if I could get the array restored with this data instead.  Has anyone tried this, or could they offer me any pointers on how to properly perform this migration?

Side note: I am a Windows person trying to move to Linux. For the most part, I can conceptually translate what I want to do (for the most part) but since I am still somewhat green in the Linux world, I know enough to be dangerous but not enough to always successfully execute my vision. Any assistance during this (frankly exciting) transition is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `As you can see, I am now here asking for help to the SU community since this assumption doesn't seem to have worked like I expected.` What's the problem/error?

Comment: When selecting "Intel ssdRaid" as my boot device following my approach outlined in the main question, I never seem to make it to the grub screen to pick my OS. Instead, I get a perpetual blinking cursor and no sign of boot activity occurring.  I intentionally left the question a bit more open ended due to my lack of confidence in my  approach to restoring the data being at all correct or even possible.  Would the mbr/gpt be properly restored using my methodology on this new logical raid device?

Comment: Actually, if you have been using UEFI boot (instead of CSM/legacy boot), you will need to re-register the EFI binary to your UEFI (NVRAM), so that your UEFI will be aware of it. Alternatively, you can mount the EFI System Partition to, for example, `/mnt` in Ubuntu live, then look for `grubx64.efi` and copy it to `/mnt/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` (create the directory where necessary).

Comment: The way you backup/restore the disk is alright. You will need to tinker a bit to move the backup GPT header to the "end" of the RAID array so that you can use the extra space though.